# UITableViewCell with dynamic height, border and space between

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm trying to create a custom UITableviewCell with dynamic height, a border and some kind of distance between cells.

I can do 2 of these things together playing with **UITableViewAutomaticDimension** and other tricks, but I really can't figure out how to get all 3 these things together. **UITableViewAutomaticDimension** really makes simple the dynamic height but then I can't add the "fake height" which let me have distance between cells.

[image: My cell]

P.S.
I really wanna avoid a manual calculation of the height of the cells based on their content because I wanna have a cell which is content can be subclassed and changed.

Comment: screenshot of output please. also how you have set botttom of self.contentview?

Comment: Assuming that's a stack view in the center, constrain its Top and Bottom with a Constant that gives you your "spacing" between the rows.

Comment: @DonMag Yes, it's a stack view. I did that, but I also need to draw a border, so it's not that easy. Now I'm trying to dynamically update the constraint between the stackview and the bottom.

Comment: @FahimParkar There is no "output" because I don't have something that is close to what I want to do.

Comment: @AlbertoSchiariti - OK - sounds like you want to embed your UI elements in a "holder" `UIView` ... that "holder" view should be the only subview of the cell's `Content View` ... then constrain that "holder" view with extra Top and Bottom spacing .... and apply your border / shadow / etc to that "holder" view.